# Javascript Motion Sensor Memory Leak in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory-leaks, html5-canvas, html5-video

I try to write a motion sensor in Javascript. For that I open a webcam mediastream with 4 frames per second with getUserMedia API, capture two images per second and compair them in a loop.

Here is the full code example:
https://traact.app/assets/issues/2/motion-sensor-memory-leak.html

Unfortunatly the code has a memory leak about ~280MB per 24 hours.
Tested in Chrome 87 and Chrome 89 dev.

What I am doing wrong here? Or it is not possible to write such kind of component on the web platform currently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was going on. In my case, it was the camera driver that caused the memory leak. When I use another USB camera, the problem is no longer there.